# Sums of squares (Equality?)

Tags: multiple-regression, sums-of-squares, quadratic-form

Given the linear model **Y**=**X**$\beta$+e, How can i prove the following claim?

$SS_{(e)}=SS_{(R)}+Y'Y$

I've done the math, and actually I think the true equality is:
$SS_{(e)}=Y'Y-SS_{(R)}$

But I'm really bad at Matrix Algebra and I don't trust myself. Which one is the correct?

Comment: It is sum of squares due to the model SS$_R$ + sum of squares due to error SS$_E$ that equals total sum of squares SS$_T$.  But I don't see how Y'Y equals total sum of squares.

Comment: I dont know if it's ok, since I've consulted several books and almost all use different notation, which confuses me a little. I understand the following:
$SS_{(e)}=(Y-X\hat{\beta})'(Y-X\hat{\beta})$ and developing it a little, I've got that $SS_{(e)}=Y'Y-\hat{\beta}'X'Y$, but $\hat{\beta}'X'Y=SS_{(R)}$, isn't it? @MichaelChernick

Comment: Maybe, but I am not familiar with it in that form.  At any rate the form of the equation on line 2 of your question is wrong and your equation on line 3 might be correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can't prove it because it is not correct.

The basic analysis of variance equation for a linear model states that
$${\rm SS}_{(T)}={\rm SS}_{(R)}+{\rm SS}_{(e)}$$
where ${\rm SS}_{(T)}$ is the total sum of squares (SS), ${\rm SS}_{(R)}$ is the regression SS and ${\rm SS}_{(e)}$ is the error or residual SS.

The residual SS is always the sum of squared residuals, SS$_{(e)}=(Y-X\hat\beta)'(Y-X\hat\beta)$, but there are two ways to define the regression SS and the total SS depending on whether one adjusts for the overall mean or not.

If you don't adjust for the overall mean, then SS$_{(T)}=Y'Y$ and SS$_{(R)}=\hat\beta'X'Y$.
In this framework, the total SS is literally the sum of squared observations.

If you do adjust for the overall mean, as is commonly done in practice, then both SS$_{(T)}$ and SS$_{(R)}$ are reduced by an amount $n\bar y^2$, where $n$ is the number of observations and $\bar y$ is the mean of $Y$.
In the framework, the total SS is the sum of squares of mean-corrected observations.
We can write SS$_{(T)}=Z'Z$ and SS$_{(R)}=\hat\beta'X'Z$ where $Z$ is equal to $Y$ with $\bar y$ subtracted from each value.